# Help with jquery GET method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm very very new to this ... so, here's my newbie question :D
What's wrong with my code snippet below? I'm not getting any response from that URL. It should return the result in plain text ... am I doing this wrongly?

```
                $.get('http://is.gd/api.php?longurl=http://www.google.com.my/', function(data) {
                  alert(data);
                },"text");
```

Comment: Are you using firebug to test your response?

Comment: Is this the URL of your server (i.e. where the site that contains this code is located)? If not please have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Yeap, using firebug to test the response.
Didn't know it has to be the same domain, I'm doing this locally ... anyway of making work locally?

Answer (score 1):

doing a quick test but try this:

```
$.get('/api.php?longurl=http://www.google.com.my/', 
        function(data)
        { 
            alert(data); 
    }
    );
```

Wont let you connect to a remote server, local only.
also removed the ","text");" which you had at the end.

Comment: http://is.gd is not his website and domain, he didn't have api.php functionality at his website

Comment: in that case he will have to write some magic code to get it working then ;-)

Comment: I've offer to him an solution at the comments to my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't do AJAX requests if http://is.gd/ is not your server. AJAX requests works only with same domain where your code is.

Comment: you need to use jsonp or some other techniques

Comment: Hmm .. then how would one get the response? According to the API here
http://is.gd/api_info.php

I'm suppose to use the get method

Comment: At the server-side you can, at the client-side (using JS) not. For example write simple php file that accepts url param and truth socket or curl library connects to the is.gd website and returns result. This php file will be at the same domain as your request and problem will be resolved.

Comment: or I could just do this instead.

  try {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
        } catch (e) {
        }

Comment: But this is not cross-browser solution.

Comment: oh ... I just needed it to work on firefox for testing purposes, maybe I should had been clear :X Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Give the relative path.

e.g. 
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});